# why we lost the ability to browse OneNote folders inside sharepoint online compared to sharepoint on-premises

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, office, onenote

We have a SharePoint 2013 on-premises site collection, and inside the document libraries we have OneNote files. now i migrated the content of the on-premises site collection to a sharepoint online site collection. where everything have been migrated correctly. but i faced issues with the OneNote files.

I faced this case, for example i got this case:-

1. Inside the on-premises document library i have a OneNote folder named "Health OneNote Pages", as follow:-
   [image]
2. and when i click on it i will get a list of OneNote files (Multiple .one files + a single "Open NoteBook.Onetoc2") + a folder named "OneNote_RecycleBin", follow-
   [image]
3. Then after completing the migration, and on the migrated online document library, I got the OneNote folder added correctly, which is great as follow:-
   [image]

But i am facing these 2 issues on the migrated online document library:-
1. When I click on the migrated OneNote folder, the OneNote will open inside OneNote desktop application (this is based on the setting we defined for the document library which is fine), instead of being able to navigate to the folder content as in the on-premsies case.
2. most importantly, I have noted that inside the the OneNote desktop application the “OneNote_RecylcleBin” folder is missing + the “Open Notebook.onetoc2” file is missing. So is this normal?

Comment: how way you were migrated content from on-prem to online?

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška using a third party tool named sharegate... but i do not think the issue is with the tool,, but rather with the way sharepoint online handle Onenote files?

Answer (score 2):

> I have noted that inside the the OneNote desktop application the “OneNote_RecycleBin” folder is missing + the “Open Notebook.onetoc2” file is missing.

A .onetoc2 file simply is the **t**able **o**f **c**ontents of a OneNote notebook. The content of the recycle bin, on the other hand, can be accessed by clicking on History > Notebook Recycle Bin > Notebook Recycle Bin.

Comment: @Flex Bohnacker thanks for the rely.. so if i got your answer correctly, then it is normal not to get any tab for the `.onetoc2`,, since this is used internally by the OneNote desktop application, to build the table of content?. second point i access the `History > Notebook Recycle Bin > Notebook Recycle Bin` for the migrated OneNote file, but i did not find any files there, although inside the on-premises folder , it contain 2 files named `OneNote_DeletedPages.one` & `Open%20Notebook.onetoc2`.. what do you think?

Comment: OneNote_DeletedPages.one simply is a _section_ within the recycle bin (in general, .one files correspond to _sections_ in the OneNote desktop application) containing all deleted pages. When opening the recycle bin in the OneNote desktop application, you should see an empty section called "Deleted Pages".

As far as I know, the .onetoc2 file within the recycle bin is used as a table of contents for the recycle bin. Therefore, it shouldn't appear in the desktop application as it is only used in the background.

Answer (score 1):

I found great article about OneNotes and working/migrating them. I hope it help you for functional migrating of OneNotes to SPO. [Link here](https://bitwizards.com/thought-leadership/blog/2016/september/microsoft-sharepoint-is-the-best-home-for-onenote)

> Migrate, Don’t Move! I can’t stress this point enough: Don’t move a
>   OneNote Notebook if it’s shared. It is quite simple to move a
>   Notebook: Just right-click on the Notebook in the left panel of
>   OneNote, select Properties and then click the Change location button.
>   However, this will break functionality for everyone else who is
>   sharing the Notebook. So we should find a better way.
>
> The trick is to recreate the Notebook from scratch in SharePoint.
>   Don’t worry; this isn’t as daunting as it sounds, and by the end of
>   this walkthrough you’ll see why I suggest this. Find where you need to
>   move the Notebook to in SharePoint—company-wide Notebooks should be
>   stored in the top level team site, department-specific Notebooks
>   should be stored in Document Libraries or SharePoint subsites with
>   unique permissions.

Comment: intersting link, although our migration tool did not mention that migrating OneNote files will be an issue... so from your reply, i should not migrate OneNote files to sharepoint online?

Comment: Try to do it by the manual in this link if it works fine, SPO working differently with these files, but you can create almost 1:1 when you will do it manually.